# Convenções de nomes para variáveis e funções no Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, convenções-de-nome, convenções

No `R`, existe muita liberdade e variedade nos nomes de funções entre os pacotes. Nomes com ponto (`get.this`), nomes em camelCase (`getThis`), nomes em snake_case (`get_this`). Isso tem seus prós e contras. Poré, o fato é que não parece haver uma padronização.

Tenho começado a estudar mais `Python` e me parece que a preocupação com readability e padronização da comunidade é maior do que no `R`. Quais as convenções de nomes para funções, variáveis, constantes etc em Python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Segundo as convenções de nomenclatura do próprio [Python Enhancement Proposal 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), algumas preocupações incluem:

**Evitar certos nomes**

Nunca usar os caracteres 'l', 'O', ou 'I' como nomes de variáveis pois, em algumas fontes, eles são indistinguíveis dos números um e zero.

**Pacote e nomes de módulos**

Os módulos devem ter nomes pequenos, sendo estes escritos em minúsculo por completo.

Ex: package

**Nomes de classes**

Os nomes de classes têm a primeira letra de cada palavra maiúscula (CamelCase).

Ex: NomeDeUmaClasse

**Nomes de funções e métodos**

Nomes de funções e métodos devem estar em letras minúsculas, com palavras separadas por *underscores* conforme seja útil para a legibilidade.

Ex: nome_de_uma_funcao

Obs: o caso misto (todas as iniciais maiúsculas, com exceção da primeira) é permitido apenas em contextos onde isso já é o estilo predominante, para manter compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

**Constantes**

Constantes são geralmente definidas em um nível de módulo e escritas em letras maiúsculas com *underscores* separando as palavras. Exemplos incluem MAX_OVERFLOW e TOTAL.

**Nomes de variáveis e parâmetros de funções e métodos**

Geralmente seguem a mesma regra das funções, devendo estar em letras minúsculas, com palavras separadas por *underscores* conforme seja útil para a legibilidade.

Obs: Usar *self* como primeiro parâmetro de um método.

Ex: nome_de_um_metodo(self):

**Identação**

A identação deve ser feita usando quatro espaços por nível.

**Linhas em branco**

Linhas em branco são recomendadas para separar funções e definições de classes (duas linhas), além de definições de métodos (uma linha).

**Espaços em branco**

O espaço em branco deve ser usado para separar operadores matemáticos, binários, de comparação e de atribuição de outros elementos.

Ex:

```
if variavel == False:
    print 2 * 3
```

Deve-se evitar o uso de espaços em branco entre parênteses e parâmetros na declaração de uma função, bem como entre uma chamada de função e o primeiro parêntese de sua lista de argumentos.

Ex: funcao(primeiro_parametro, segundo_parametro)

Comment: Guilherme, você poderia colocar exemplos para todos os casos? Acho que ficaria melhor para ilustrar! Abs

Comment: Acho que agora ficou mais completo! Abs

Comment: Só uma correção: PEP-8 não diz nada sobre espaços entre argumentos de uma função - apenas [objeta espaços entre os parênteses (ou chaves) e os parâmetros](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves). Se olhar os exemplos da PEP, porém, notará que sempre há espaços entre os argumentos (felizmente!), como em `spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2})`.

Comment: Corrigido! Obrigado pelo lembrete (=